# Can the Vivosmart HR and a chest strap be used simultaneously with Garmin Connect software?

Tags: heart-rate-monitor

I'm very close to purchasing a Garmin Vivosmart HR. It appears to be a good 24/7 fitness tracker.

However when I'm training, I would prefer to have the accuracy of a chest strap HR monitor.

I realize that the Vivosmart HR can not connect directly to external HR monitors and chest straps.

My question is, is the Garmin Connect software clever enough to accept data from two devices, to use the Vivosmart data for 'general' monitoring, but to prioritize data from the chest strap when this is available during training.

Thanks for any advice or thought from those familiar with the devices and software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pairing hardware.